# piwik tracker status 500 installation error

Tags: apache, matomo

I have to configure [PIWIK](http://piwik.org/)
for web analytics. I am configuring it on localhost so that I can understand it before finaly deployment. My OS is centos 7. During installation, I am facing following error in apache webserver (httpd)

> [Mon Nov 23 16:45:54.946214 2015] [:error] [pid 16750] [client
>   ::1:38222] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with
>   message 'The configuration file
>   {`/var/www/html/analytics/piwik/config/config.ini.php`} has not been
>   found or could not be read.' in
>   /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php:64
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0
>   /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php(45):
>   Piwik\Application\Kernel\EnvironmentValidator->checkConfigFileExists('/var/www/html/a...',
>   false)
>
> #1
>   /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/core/Application/Environment.php(185):
>   Piwik\Application\Kernel\EnvironmentValidator->validate()
>
> #2
>   /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/core/Application/Environment.php(94):
>   Piwik\Application\Environment->validateEnvironment()
>
> #3 /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/piwik.php(56):
>   Piwik\Application\Environment->init()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/analytics/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php
>   on line 64, referer: http://localhost/analytics/piwik

A warning is show that tracker status 500 is also shown. What is the problem and with my installation. I have changed permission of `config/` and `tmp/` to **777** also.

Comment: Does the file `config.ini.php`exist? Provide `ls -lh config/` output

Comment: No it does not ? I think it is created at installation time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same error on Ubuntu 14.04 during Piwik setup. After some investigation, I saw that the `config.ini.php` file was actually not created before the setup wizard:

```
root@*****:/opt/piwik/config# ll
total 736
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 oct.  22 14:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root       4096 oct.  22 14:00 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 juin  16  2015 environment/
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      38724 oct.  22 14:00 global.ini.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3230 août  14 04:41 global.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     695563 oct.  22 14:00 manifest.inc.php
```

The warning message was indicated as "optional" so I continued through the installation steps hoping that the file would be created during that process and that was the case:

```
root@*****:/opt/piwik/config# ll
total 740
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 18 17:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root       4096 oct.  22 14:00 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   2362 janv. 18 17:33 config.ini.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 juin  16  2015 environment/
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      38724 oct.  22 14:00 global.ini.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3230 août  14 04:41 global.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     695563 oct.  22 14:00 manifest.inc.php
```

As a conclusion, if you run into that error message during first phase of setup, don't worry, keep on the installation process, there is a chance it will resolve on itself ;).

Comment: But its not a better style of installation that you should continue without considering errors and warnings